# Does Rails run initializers for rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, initializer, rake-task

Are the scripts from config/initializers executed when I run rake task?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It does if your rake task depends on `:environment`.

i.e, you declare your task like so:

```
task :my_task => :environment do
     ...
end
```

Answer (score 2):

**Mostly yes.** rake loads a complete rails environment including initializers, when your task depends on `:environment`.